# SwiftUI Shape does not updates

Tags: swift, swiftui

In ZStack I have `ForEach` loop to insert some shapes `SkinShape`:

```
Struct Canvas: View {
    @ObservedObject var glyphModel: GDGlyphViewModel
    @Binding var tool: GDEditorTool
    @Binding var selectedObject: UUID?

    var body: some View {
    ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal], showsIndicators: true) {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                mouseReader(geometry: geometry)
        
                ForEach(glyphModel.glyph?.originControls ?? []) { control in
                    SkinShape(control: control).stroke()
                }
                ForEach(glyphModel.positionBinders.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                    PointShape(point: position(index))
                        .foregroundColor( isSelected(index: index)
                        ? .blue : .gray)
                        .....
```

And outside:

```
struct SkinShape: Shape  {
    @State var control : GDOriginControl
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in
            print ("Making Shape \(control.id)")
            for index in 0..<control.origin.sticks.count-1 {
                print (control.origin.sticks[index].offset.cgPoint)
                let this = control.origin.sticks[index].offset.cgPoint
                path.move(to: control.point.cgPoint + this)
                let next  = control.origin.sticks[(index+1)].offset.cgPoint
                path.addLine(to: control.point.cgPoint + next)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But shape never changes during redrawing view. In console I can see numeric changes, everything except `SkinShape` is refreshed,  `glyphModel.objectWillChange.send()` is fired with DragGesture, I can move points and change SkinShape data. But shapes never change, only refreshes when I replace content of `GDGlyphViewModel`. How to push those Shapes read their data and redraw?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need state wrapper in shape (it is not modified inside, but prevents modifications from outside):

```
struct SkinShape: Shape  {
    var control : GDOriginControl     // << no state here !!
// .. other code
}
```